# Showing an entire ASP website as an image

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, asp-classic

I have an ASP website that gets data from SQL queries and puts them into divs and then, superimposes the divs over an image. The only problem is that when people try to save the image, they do not get the data or the divs with the image.

Is there anyway I can combine the divs and the image into one single picture using ASP or even ASP.NET? This way when people try to save the images, they get the original image and also the data that is put on top of the image as well.

I have been trying to use the

```
Response.ContentType = "image/gif"
```

tag in a separate page and tried to call that page as an image but that's not working when you have HTML combined with the ASP. Can anyone please help.

Comment: My boss says that most people who use that part of the website are not technologically advanced and they just usually right click on the image to get it and therefore, we need to make it like that

Comment: you usually do such things by generating a pdf, don't you?

Comment: @josneville There is a fantastic ASP component I swear by for this sort of thing by Persits called [ASPpdf](http://www.asppdf.com) look at the documentation at [13.1 ImportFromUrl Method](http://asppdf.com/manual_13.html#13_1). It runs on the server-side directly in [tag:asp] no need for client side code.

Comment: PhantomJS can do such a thing very nice, open source, runs smoothly on the server side, export to jpg or pdf, what else do you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youc can use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library to take "screenshots" of entire pages.

**Update:**

Apparently it is possibe server-side as well (using ASP.NET tho) by using WebBrowswer control (yes it can be used in ASP.NET as well). [Take a look](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-generate-webpage-thumbmail-screenshot-image)

Comment: I am working under really strict instructions. I can't use non-approved javascript because of company policy and restrictions. I HAVE to stick with ASP which is frustrating.

Comment: Well you have to compromise somewhere. Page is rendered on the client (styles, formats etc.) so it *has to be* client code, it cannot be done server-side.

Comment: I stand corrected. Take a look at the second solution (updated the answer)